# Creating symbolic links in AIX 6.1 server

Tags: unix, aix

I'm trying to create sym-links using the following commands :

```
root:d2stud -> $ ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.a /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a
ln: 0653-421 /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a exists.
    Specify -f to remove /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a before linking.
(/stud/config/git_install)
root:d2stud -> $


root:d2stud -> $ ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypto.a /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a
ln: 0653-421 /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a exists.
    Specify -f to remove /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a before linking.
(/stud/config/git_install)
root:d2stud -> $
```

I did not get what I need to remove as specified by the error message.

Can anyone explain how I can resolve the error.

Comment: You have two choices: (1) Either remove `/opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a` before issuing your command.  (2) Add the `-f` flag for `ln` to remove the destination file.

Comment: Is it safe to do that. So where do I add -f option in the command.

Comment: Whether safe or not, you can tell since you want to overwrite the existing file.  Regarding the flag, you can say: `ln -sf /usr/lib/libssl.a /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a`

Comment: (If it is not late) You shouldn't play with shared libs, you could render the system unusable. Ask the sysadmin to decide which version of OpenSsl is suitable, and where/how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to the side:

```
mv <orig-path> <new-path>
```

i.e.

```
mv /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a-orig
```

then if you want to go back like it was, move it back:

```
mv /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a-orig /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a.
```

If or when you want to go back, you would need to remove what you created at /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a (such as the symlink you are trying to create).